# HTML in IF statement not working properly

Tags: php, html, if-statement

So i have the following code:

```
<?php
$users_id = $_POST['users_id'];
    if ($users_id=="1");
    {
    ?>
        <td><select name="User">
        <option></option>
        <option>John</option>
        <option>Jack</option>
        </select></td>  
<?php
    }
    if ($users_id!=="1");
    {
    ?>      
        <td align="left"> <input type="text" name="User" /><br></td></tr>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

I want only one form to be shown (dropdown or input), but i always get both of them and
I can't figure it out what is wrong with my if statement.
Please help!
Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Why using ; in the end of IF statement ??? Does PHP allow this

Comment: PHP (and many other C-influenced languages) does allow semicolon after IF, and it is a common source of bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your code and paste this one...
it will surely work

```
<?php
$user_id = (isset($_POST['users_id'])) ? $_POST['users_id'] : '';
if($user_id == 1){
?>
<td><select name="User">
<option></option>
<option>John</option>
<option>Jack</option>
</select></td>
<?php
} else {
?>
<td align="left"> <input type="text" name="User" /><br></td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
```

**Changes made in your code**
done validation of post field,
removed ; from if condition,
used if-else instead of if-if,
placed `</tr>` after all processing, else it will return an visible error

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you used identical operator `!==` when you should not, as I see you using equality `==` in the other `if` statement.

And, more importantly, you put semicolon after your `if` conditions! This will create an empty statement after the `if` condition and anything after that will run no matter it satisfies with the condition or not.

Try changing

```
if ($users_id!=="1");
```

into

```
if ($users_id!="1")
```

and

```
if ($users_id=="1");
```

to

```
if ($users_id=="1")
```

Answer (score 2):

> if ($users_id!="1");

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

remove semicolons from if-lines and change second if-condition to:

```
if ($users_id!="1")
```

or use this syntax:

```
if ($users_id=="1") {
    // select
} else {
   // input
}
```

Comment: Yes, semicolons were the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of two `if()`s, use `if/else` blocks:

```
if( $users_id=="1" ) {

  // ... something

} else {

  // something else

}
```

Please do not use `===` unless you understand the difference between `==` and `===`. See docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I get error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Answer (score 2):

Two changes

1. Remove semi colon after if condition

   i`f ($users_id!="1")`
2. Change !==  to !=

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon which is present there after if condition

Answer (score 0):

please check your code change

```
if ($users_id!=="1");
```

to

```
if ($users_id!="1")
```

also drop if(); to if() and please read about [If else](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if ($users_id!=="1");//correct->if ($users_id!=="1")

```
<?php
$users_id = $_POST['users_id'];

    if ($users_id==1);
    {

     echo   "<td><select name='User'>
        <option></option>
        <option>John</option>
        <option>Jack</option>
        </select></td>";  

    }
    if($users_id!=1)
    {

        echo "<td align='left'> <input type='text' name='User' /><br></td></tr>";

    }
    ?>
```